# Do Not See What Invalid Syntax is in Line of Code

Tags: python, numpy, syntax-error

I do not understand what the syntax error is for that particular line of code.

```
print("pred is equal to predictions: {}".format(np.all(pred == 
gbrt.predict(X_test))))
decision_function = gbrt.decision_function(X_test)
print("Decision function minimum: {:.2f} maximum: {:.2f}".format(
        np.min(decision_function), np.max(decision_function)))
X_test.shape: (25, 2)
Decision function shape: (25,)
Decision function:

File "<ipython-input-17-1457aa7b42c8>", line 34
    Decision function shape: (25,)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `Decision function shape:` is not a valid Python statement. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: `X_test.shape: (25, 2)` is also not valid, I'm not sure why you didn't get an error there.

Comment: The syntax to set an array's shape is `np.reshape(X_test, (3, 2))`, `np.reshape(decision_function, (25,))`

Comment: Thank you for your help! That is what I needed to know.